# How to get User ID from photo preview URL?

Tags: facebook, url, get, photo

Dears is there anyway to retrieve user ID from picture preview URL within facebook?
For example this is the photo preview URL https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=10151312556380001&set=a.10151217166815001.774705.830875000&type=1&theater
This is the photo ID 10151312556380001
Can I use it to get the user ID? the user who uploaded the photo.

Thanks

Comment: looks like it's between the a. and the last set of numbers - `10151217166815001` in this case: https://www.facebook.com/10151217166815001 (at least that gives me a redirect to see if I know this user)

Comment: Why do you want to do that?

Comment: @pherris I dont want to do that through the browser. I wanna do it through Facebook's SDK.

Comment: @WizKid Im building something in which I get the photo preview URL and need to figure out the owner ID wthout going into the browser, no human interaction should be involved.

Comment: looks like I had the wrong number, but the id does seem to be in that url... see answer below.

Comment: Where do you get the photo preview URL from? Seems like you are doing something wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The user id is part of the url, you just have to parse it out.

JavaScript example:

```
var spliturl = "https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=10151312556380001&set=a.10151217166815001.774705.830875000&type=1&theater".split(".");
console.log(spliturl[spliturl.length-1].split("&")[0]);
```

The console.log output is:

> 830875000

If I query the graph API for this user (https://graph.facebook.com/v2.2/830875000?access_token=MY_SECRET_TOKEN) I get this JSON back:

```
{
   "id": "830875000",
   "first_name": "Alaa",
   "last_name": "Abdelhaq",
   "link": "https://www.facebook.com/app_scoped_user_id/10155109919315001/",
   "name": "Alaa Abdelhaq"
}
```

Presumably this is the ID you are looking for.

Comment: Cool, if this answers your question can you please click the checkmark next to the answer? Thanks!